# Stripe's radar change via API c#.net - stripe.net library

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I hope i can solve my problem here with your profession. Thank to all come and read.

How can I change the radar setting of stripe account via API? (I dont want to change it on stripe's account dashboard must API)
I have installed the stripe.net library but i can not search any about changing radar vis this library.

This is the details I found on my stripe account when i make change.

> 

```
/v1/rules/request_3ds_if_3ds_required

POST
{
  "enabled": "false"
}

GET
{
  "id": "request_3ds_if_3ds_required",
  "object": "rule",
  "action": "request_credentials",
  "created": 0,
  "credentials": [
    "three_d_secure"
  ],
  "default": true,
  "enabled": false,
  "predicate": ":card_3d_secure_support: in ('required')",
  "review_priority": null,
  "rule_text": ":card_3d_secure_support: in ('required')",
  "stripe_authored": false
}
```

Im looking for the code to change the stripe's radar setting via API (c# .net | stripe.net library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no public APIs for Radar rules yet. You can only manage the Radar rules via Dashboard at this moment.